# Oracle SQL aggregate functionality

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, date-arithmetic

I have a script:

```
select 
  regexp_replace(b.username, '[0-9]', '') username, a.wait_class, count(*)
from 
  v$active_session_history a, dba_users b
where 
  a.user_id=b.user_id and
  a.sample_time>sysdate - &minutes/1440
group by 
  regexp_replace(b.username, '[0-9]', ''), a.wait_class
order by 
  3 desc
```

and its output is something like:

```
USERNAME         WAIT_CLASS      COUNT(*) 
UMESS            Commit               139 
VITPOINT         User I/O             126 
VITPOINT         <NULL>                69
```

How do I break it down into HOURLY segments, so that the output looks like:

```
USERNAME         START TIME   WAIT_CLASS      COUNT(*) 
UMESS            10:00:00     Commit               66 
UMESS            11:00:00     Commit               73
VITPOINT         10:00:00     User I/O             62
VITPOINT         11:00:00     User I/O             64
etc
```

I would like the interval to be an **&** variable entered in minutes.  So if 60 minutes is the input, then the interval is hourly, for example.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has been a nice challenge. I used a number generator to generate a sequence between the max and min sample time. Use the `&bucket_minutes` variable to provide your interval in minutes.

```
with cte_basedata as (
    select regexp_replace(u.username, '[0-9]', '') username, ash.wait_class, ash.sample_time
    from v$active_session_history ash
    join dba_users u on (ash.user_id = u.user_id)  
    where ash.sample_time>sysdate - &minutes/1440
), cte_ng as (
    select (sysdate - (level-1) / 24 / 60 * &bucket_minutes) bucket_end, (sysdate - (level) / 24 / 60 * &bucket_minutes) bucket_start
    from dual
    connect by level <= (select extract (day from (max(sample_time) - min(sample_time)) * 24 * 60) / &bucket_minutes + 1 from cte_basedata)
), cte_data as (
    select d.*, cte_ng.bucket_start
    from cte_basedata d
    left outer join cte_ng on (d.sample_time between cte_ng.bucket_start and cte_ng.bucket_end)
)
select username, wait_class, bucket_start, count(*) from cte_data
group by username, wait_class, bucket_start
```

Comment: Both solutions work but I like this one more where the buckets are divided within the main interval. Thank you for your awesome effort!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to fit your needs:

```
select 
regexp_replace(b.username, '[0-9]', '') username, a.wait_class,
  to_char( round( ( a.sample_time - trunc( a.sample_time ) ) * (24*(60/&minutes)) )/ (24*(60/&&minutes)) + trunc( a.sample_time ), 'HH24:MI:SS' ) start_time, -- Used to round the time to the nearest XX minutes
  count(*)
from 
  v$active_session_history a, dba_users b
where 
  a.user_id=b.user_id and
  a.sample_time>sysdate - &&minutes/1440
group by 
  regexp_replace(b.username, '[0-9]', ''), a.wait_class, to_char( round( ( a.sample_time - trunc( a.sample_time ) ) * (24*(60/&minutes)) )/ (24*(60/&&minutes)) + trunc( a.sample_time ), 'HH24:MI:SS' )
order by 
  3 desc;
```

The problem is that you say:

> I would like the interval to be an & variable entered in minutes. So if 60 minutes is the input, then the interval is hourly, for example.

The thing is that if you want for example a 30 minutes interval then in your where clause you take only the last 30 minutes then you will have only two lines per user/wait_class.

So you need to add a second parameter like this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(b.username, '[0-9]', '') username,
  a.wait_class,
  to_char( round( ( cast(a.sample_time as date) - trunc( cast(a.sample_time as date) ) ) * (24*(60/
  &&minutes)) )                         / (24*(60/
  &&minutes))                          + TRUNC( CAST(a.sample_time AS DATE) ), 'HH24:MI:SS' ) start_time, -- Used to round the time to the nearest XX minutes
  COUNT(                                        *)
FROM v$active_session_history a,
  dba_users b
WHERE a.user_id  =b.user_id
and a.sample_time>sysdate -
  &&from_minutes                /1440
GROUP BY regexp_replace(b.username, '[0-9]', ''),
  a.wait_class,
  to_char( round( ( cast(a.sample_time as date) - trunc( cast(a.sample_time as date) ) ) * (24*(60/
  &&minutes)) )                         / (24*(60/
  &&minutes))                          + TRUNC( CAST(a.sample_time AS DATE) ), 'HH24:MI:SS' )
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Hope this helps

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your awesome effort!